# Form inside a material-ui Dialog is not submitting on Enter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a modal dialog with two buttons, one of which should work as a submit button.
I'd like <kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the submit as well.

Here's my code for this component:

```
import React, { FormEvent } from 'react';
import { Button, Dialog, DialogActions, DialogContent, DialogContentText } from '@material-ui/core';

interface Props {
  close: () => void;
  onSubmit: () => void;
}

export default (props: Props) => {
  const handleSubmit = (e: FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onSubmit();
    props.close();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog open onClose={props.close}>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText>
            You are about to submit the text. Are you sure you are done?
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button type="button" color="primary" variant="outlined" size="small">No, there is more to do</Button>
          <Button type="submit" color="primary" variant="contained" size="small">Yes, I&apos;m done here</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </form>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Clicking on a button works, <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not. I tried to put the `form` inside `DialogActions` — same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to the `keyup` event and tell the `Dialog` to submit and close if `e.keyCode` is `13` (which is the key code for <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```js
<Dialog
  onKeyUp={(e) => {
    const ENTER = 13;
    console.log(e.keyCode)

    if (e.keyCode === ENTER) {
      props.onSubmit();
      props.onClose();
    }
  }}
>
  {...}
</Dialog>
```

**EDIT:** if you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `onsubmit` event will fire when the `input`s or the submit `button` is in focused. You can add `autofocus` to the submit `Button` so when the `Dialog` is opened the `Button` will be focused by default. The user can then close the dialog by pressing Enter while the button is in focused

```js
<Button
  autoFocus
  type="submit"
>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64498415/form-inside-a-material-ui-dialog-is-not-submitting-on-enter]

Comment: Thank you, but I was hoping to find out why the normal 'submit on enter' logic does not work in this case.

Comment: Looks like you need to make one of the `input` or the submit button focused if you want the users to submit the form by pressing Enter @ptkvsk. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, autoFocus seems like a more idiomatic solution to me!

Answer (score 3):

## Update 2022

keyCode is being depreciated.

use:

e.key

example:

```
if (e.key === 'Enter') {...}
```